# WordPress: can't achieve direct image access redirection via .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, server

My goal is the following: when a user tries to access an image (or any other attachments in /wp-content/uploads/) I need to redirect him to a processor PHP file that will check if a user is logged in and the file is uploaded by that user.

I've come to this solution so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*wp-content/uploads/.*
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ file-processor.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And it just doesn't work.  I've tried a huge amount of different combinations and had no luck. And then I've decided to try something simpler and found out that I can't even redirect directly accessed images via the following code (while it works fine for any other pages of the website):

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
```

And that's part is really confusing... Should there be some different treatment to the files that are accessed directly?

To make it clear. With the last code I got the following behaviour:

- If I try to access any page on the website (ex.: "siteurl.com" or "siteurl.com/about"), then I get redirection to "https://example.com/" as expected.
- If I try to access media "siteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/someimg.jpg", then I can access this media and see it, while I still expect to be redirected to "https://example.com", but I don't get any redirection.

The same problem happens with directly accessed files from my theme. I still can access them despite this last redirect rule in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
```

Could you please explain how to redirect directly accessed files then?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be behind a front-end-proxy that is intended to serve your static content. (Nginx is commonly used for this.) The proxy serves the static content, completely bypassing your application server (Apache / `.htaccess`). This provides great performance at the expense of some functionality.

Check the HTTP response headers when requesting one of these images. You may get a clue as to what is happening by checking the `Server` HTTP response header.

Possible solutions would be to either:

- Make an exception in the front-end proxy to exclude the `/wp-content/uploads` directory.

OR

- Reference these images/resources by a different URL to the actual filesystem path.

  Since you are wanting to "protect" these resources you would need to store them outside of the public HTML space (ie. above the document root) - so they are not accessible via the proxy. You can then use the same URL (ie. `/wp-content/uploads/...`) if you wish, but the script (`file-processor.php`) would read the file from this alternative location.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really get about "front-end-proxy". Server-side magic isn't my niche. But I've ended up saving images outside of the public HTML space (basically, outside of the generic "public_html" folder) and then creating a script that checks if a user is logged in and if he has the right to get access to the file with a specific name. I've used a new WordPress CPT to set up a relationship between a user and files. Now it's all working like a charm.