# Is there any way to open another file when accessing an image via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like when accessing the url https://www.italinea.com.br/uploads/jx5rufam7adfwd75pi6c.jpg, which is an existing file on the server, open the php file https://www.italinea.com.br/image.php.
Which htaccess rule do I use?

I tried to use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.jpg image.php [L,QSA]
```

But as it is an existing file, it opens the image and not the .php file

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete contents of your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.+)\.jpg image.php [L,QSA]
> ```

This is the right idea and should "work", although it could be simplified a bit. And it is rather generic, so matches every `.jpg` request.

If this is not working then either:

- You have a conflict with other directives in the `.htaccess` file (the order of directives can be important).
- You have a front-end proxy that is serving your static content. This is a problem if the URL being requested maps to a physical file as the application server (ie. `.htaccess`) is then completely bypassed.

  If this is the case then see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69428478/369434) to the following related question:
  [WordPress: can't achieve direct image access redirection via .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428119/wordpress-cant-achieve-direct-image-access-redirection-via-htaccess)